# Create one iOS app, but distribute to several clients

Tags: ios

I'm a NET developer who embarked on iOS / iPhone dev a week ago. I have two questions:

1) I need to make an app which will be distributed to several clients. So things like Logo, title etc... need to be different for each of them.

(The idea is to create one app, but distribute to several clients)

What approach do you recommend?

2) How to increase my learning pace with iOS, any good quality resource you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Apple provides two solutions.

   1. The first solution is to have the client sign up for the iOS Developer Enterprise Program. With the iOS Developer Enterprise Program, they will be able to develop/distribute multiple custom applications on their devices.
   2. The second solution is to offer your customized app as a B2B app on the iTunes Connect portal. With a B2B app, you specify the customer and the agreed upon price per copy.  Your client then enrolls for volume purchasing and will then be able to buy the app.  According to app, there is a minimum app price of $9.99 USD and only the customers that you specify are able to purchase the app.
2. For learning, I started with the following resources:

   - Coccoa Programming for Mac OS X 2nd Edition" by Aaron Hillegass (book)
   - Object-Oriented Programming and the Objective-C Language (PDF)
   - The Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language (PDF)

Once I understood the basics of Objective-C, Xcode, and the Interface builder, I found the best resources for learning were the Samples apps and developer library on the developer portal.

For specific questions, I've had the best luck with stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

for logo, place images on server and at login or loading time, download that image based on client type, and store in NSUserDefaults so that no need to download it next time, and for learning, read tutorials from [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials), once, you have grip on basics, you will easily able to troubleshoot and solve complex problems